# Better way to have an key - value relationship with guaranteed order iteration javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, key, iteration

I am building a little project of mine and have found no other solution to having a key value relationship with the order of iteration guaranteed.

What I have come up with so far is this,

```
var Plate = function () {

    this.children = [];
    this.childrenKeys = [];
};

var proto = Plate.prototype;

proto.addChild = function (key, child) {

    this.childrenKeys.push(key);
    this.children.push(child);
};

proto.removeChild = function (key) {

    var index = this.childrenKeys.indexOf(key);
    delete(this.children[index]);
};

proto.update = function () {

    this.children.forEach(function (child) {

        child.update();
    });
};
```

While this does work and I can add to `Plate` with a key and a value, and I can delete from the plate with a key it just doesn't seem right to do so.

I understand I cannot use an object and `for...in` as the order of iteration is completely inconsistent and I cannot have it be like that.

Is this the correct method for doing this or is there a build in javascript way of doing this?

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you use a single array and use `arr.push({'key': key, 'child': child}`)? That way you can be sure that all your data is always nicely tied together. However, there is no built-in insert-ordered key-value container in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use an array of objects where the objects contain the key and value?

```
var list = [
    { key: '2', value: 'foo' },
    { key: 'abc', value: 'bar' }
];

// Usage
alert(list[0].key); // '2'
alert(list[0].value); // 'foo'
```

Here is your code using this method (untested).

```
var Plate = function () {

    this.list = []
};

var proto = Plate.prototype;

proto.addChild = function (key, child) {

    this.list.push({ key: key, child: child });
};

proto.removeChild = function (key) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.list.length; i++) {
        if (this.list[i].key === key) {
            delete(this.list[i]);
            return;
        }
    }
};

proto.update = function () {

    for (var i = 0; i < this.list.length; i++) {
        this.list[i].child.update();
    }
};
```

Comment: This was what I after it seemed strange to store the keys and the value in different arrays, let me tie it into my code and I will accept :)

Comment: Worked perfectly thanks :) Instead though I used `forEach`, thanks again!